# Injective objects in the category of finite groups.

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, finite-groups, injective-module

I have to describe the injective objects of the category of finite groups. I see that 1 is an injective object, but are there any others? If yes why, if no why not?

Comment: Please have a look at [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) and add some context to your question.

Comment: Assume that $G\neq\{e\}$ is an injective object in finite groups. Let $G\ni x\neq e$. Assume that $\operatorname{ord}(x)=n$. Define $X=(x)$, $Y=\mathbb{Z}/(mn)\mathbb{Z}$ and $f:X\to Y$ defined by $f(x^k)=mk$. Since $G$ is injective, we have a homomorphism $g:Y\to G$ such that $X\to G$ is $g\circ f$. Let $y=g(1)\in G$. Then $y^m=x$. Therefore, in $G$ we should have arbitrary roots of all elements, $G$ must be divisible. If we take $m$ to be the order of $G$, then $e=y^m=x$.

Comment: How do you get that the m-th power of y is x?

Comment: With such a hubristic user name you should be able to answer this question yourself.